# Short form to indicate coordinate phrases

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, clauses

As I am not a native speaker of English, I often get stuck in terms of "*phraseology*" (indeed). So I'll try to make it clear using example.

> People with high rate of A often tend to memorize a lot, while 
>    people with low rate of A often tend to forget a lot.

Two sentences are logically parallel, but converse in meaning (each one is only part of fact).

I am wondering if there are some expressions that can replace such long clause (just like *vice versa* and so on).

Comment: Rate of A is directly proportional to memory.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want here. Do you want suggestions about trimming long sentences?

Comment: Yes, what I want is to shorten long sentence to make it less repeating. Analogous with the usage of "vice versa".

Comment: you can try to rephrase the sentence like I did. There are no rules or a established ways to do so. Please see my first comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might say the statements are [**converses**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/converse#nav2) of each other.

i.e. "While people with a high rate of A tend to have strong memories, the converse is true for those with low A."

It doesn't reduce the sentence by many words, but it does help avoid repeating yourself.